# How to continue play the videos in playlist in tvOS by using TVML?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I'm developing a tvOS app by using TVML templates providing by Apple.

I have trouble with continuing to play the videos while users are in the playlist screen.

How to continue to play the next video after they complete a video?

Answer (score 0):

```
    video.resumeTime = metadata.resumeTime;
```

The resumeTime is used to communicate the time at which a user previously stopped
watching this asset, a bookmark. If this property is present the user will be
prompted to resume playback from the point or start the asset over.
resumeTime is the number of seconds from the beginning of the asset.

See more information here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TVMLAudioVideo/